# fancybox v2 thumbnail gallery not working in IE <=8 (href is null or not an object)

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

My gallery works as expected in all browsers except IE<=8. Below is my anchor tag click event as well as the error message I'm getting when viewing in IE8.

Any thoughts?

Anchor tag:

```
<a href="#" id="showPics">View<br />12-Picture<br />Portfolio</a>
```

JS click event:

```
$('#showPics').click(function () {
        $.fancybox([
                {
                    'href': '/Images/Top20/01.jpg',
                    'title': '1 of 12'
                },
                {
                    'href': '/Images/Top20/02.jpg',
                    'title': '2 of 12'
                },
                {
                    'href': '/Images/Top20/03.jpg',
                    'title': '3 of 12'
                },
                {
                    'href': '/Images/Top20/04.jpg',
                    'title': '4 of 12'
                },
                {
                    'href': '/Images/Top20/05.jpg',
                    'title': '5 of 12'
                },
                {
                    'href': '/Images/Top20/06.jpg',
                    'title': '6 of 12'
                },
                {
                    'href': '/Images/Top20/07.jpg',
                    'title': '7 of 12'
                },
                {
                    'href': '/Images/Top20/08.jpg',
                    'title': '8 of 12'
                },
                {
                    'href': '/Images/Top20/09.jpg',
                    'title': '9 of 12'
                },
                {
                    'href': '/Images/Top20/10.jpg',
                    'title': '10 of 12'
                },
                {
                    'href': '/Images/Top20/11.jpg',
                    'title': '11 of 12'
                },
                {
                    'href': '/Images/Top20/12.jpg',
                    'title': '12 of 12'
                },
        ], {

            prevEffect: 'none',
            nextEffect: 'none',
            padding: '3',
            mouseWheel: 'true',
            helpers: {
                title: {
                    type: 'outside'
                },
                overlay: {
                    opacity: 0.8,
                    css: {
                        'background-color': '#000'
                    }
                },
                thumbs: {
                    width: 85,
                    height: 85
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

Error message from IE8:

[image: error messsage]

Fancybox.js code

[image: fancybox_thumbs_js_line41]

Comment: {
                    'href': '/Images/Top20/12.jpg',
                    'title': '12 of 12'
                }, <------ Extra Comma?

Comment: ya that comma would cause problems

Comment: The extra comma was the issue... thanks @wirey

Comment: no problem :)  IE is very picky about everything

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "/" character at the beginning of your href strings